# WPF. Get clicked row item values

Tags: wpf

I have datagrid. Each row is element of OBservableCollection declared in cs file.
Each DataGridRow has the extra column with Delete button and click event.

How do I get the corresponding element of my OBservableCollection in button click event function?

Comment: How do you populate your data grid?  Certain methods of populating it would lend themselves well to a clean solution to this problem.  Are you using data binding?  Can you please add some (minimal) XAML, and if you are using data binding, some of the code you are binding to.

Answer (score 4):

If you hook your button's click event, the sender should be button. The DataContext on that button should be the row item:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyClass data = (sender as FrameworkElement).DataContext as MyClass;
}
```

Comment: relief: If it works, then dont forget to mark it as the answer!

Comment: @relie: You can always mark an anwer, you just cannot upvote it yet (marking is done via the checkmark outline)